# Connecting DHCP embedded device to Windows 10 PC using Ethernet cable

Tags: linux, windows, networking, linux-networking, dhcp

I have a custom embedded Linux device that I need to connect to using SSH for work.

This device uses DHCP to get its own IP from the network (using an Ethernet cable).

I used to use a router in between them but now I'd like to plug both together directly, if possible.

I'm using Windows 10 Pro and would like to hook it up with an Ethernet cable directly to the embedded device.

I tried all kind of network configuration but to no avail. (setting up static IP in advance, etc)

I also tried to let Windows get its own "IP" (funky looking i.e. 169.254.72.105) and use that one but I can only see data being SENT to the device but none is received.

[image: screenshot]

Other weird fact: if I open a command line prompt and ping it. It replies 100% of the time. So I'm wondering if that IP is even leading to the proper place or it's only Win10 playing tricks with me.

```
Pinging 169.254.72.105 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 169.254.72.105: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 169.254.72.105: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 169.254.72.105: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 169.254.72.105: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

This is similar as if I'd be connecting some Raspberry Pi directly to my workstation but for some reason I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing to get it working.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Why don't you connect it directly to your network?

Comment: @joeqwerty because my main router isn't in the same room. that device has a screen that i need to interact with so i'd need to move from room to room constantly. if i could hook it up directly to my workstation then i could put it on my desk; which would make it much easier to work with. thanks for the reply

Comment: What IP does your Windows machien have (you didn't write that) and which one does the device have? 169.254.72.105 is APIPA and only avaible for compliant devices (like Windows). You can "sent" and "reveived" data in the screenshot, but that's not "the device", that's you local Windows IP Stack (not even raw packets). If you set one IP on the device and another one (in the same subnet) on your windows, those will communicate (except you drop stuff in your firewall).